# Double slash in return value from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Get()
{
    var res = GetResult();
    // res is a JSON {"hello": "how\are\you"}
    return Ok(res);
}
```

I'm getting in the result:

```
{"hello": "how\\are\\you"}
```

How to remove the double slash from the reusult? Why they're being added?

Answer (score 3):

> Why they're being added?

Because that's how you print a backslash in JSON. `\` is a special character. It pairs with the next character(s) to define what it prints. For example, `\n` means to add a new line, not printing "\n". `\\` means a print a single backslash.

The server (your code) and the client using your application will understand this escape sequence just fine.

Answer (score 1):

These \ are not part of the string but only one i.e. \ is part of string. another \ is added as a escape character only.

if you print this you will only get single slash not double these are just representational value at the time of debug only.

Check live code : [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BtruVT)

[image]

[Escape Characters](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_character_escapes.htm#:%7E:text=C%23%20-%20Character%20Escapes%20%20%20%20Escape,%22rnHello%22%20in%20%22rHellonWorld.%22%20%209%20more%20rows%20)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove them since you have them in json already. If  you want to get rid of them fix  json of the action

```
var res = GetResult();
res.Replace("\\"," ");
 return Ok(res);
```